# how to create udf in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to create a function ......

curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8091/functions/v1/libraries/math/function/dateEpoc -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"name": "dateEpoc", "code": "function dateEpoc(epoc) { let date = new Date(); return date.setUTCSeconds(epoc); }"}' -u Administrator:password

but I am getting an error

[image: img_error]

Connected to localhost (::1) port 8091 (#0)
Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
POST /functions/v1/libraries/math/function/dateEpoc HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8091
Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjp0aGlyZGV5ZUAzMQ==
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

upload completely sent off: 7 out of 7 bytes
HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:19:52 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Couchbase Server
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Answer (score 1):

The 404 is down to the fact that you are using the wrong service to create the javascript function body.
Change the port from 8091 to 8093 - this will direct the request to the N1QL service rather than ns_server, and the request should be processed properly.

Comment: thank you @Marco Greco . i had also tried with port 8093 its executing well through postman but not executing through cmd....

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

UDF on Couchbase 6.6 is in Developer Preview Mode. So you need to enable these preview features here: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/developer-preview/preview-mode.html

After that, you can create functions via the web query console:

```
CREATE FUNCTION to_meters() { args[0] * 0.3048 };
```

Here is the documentation: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/userfun.html

Comment: thank you for your quick reply . i had tried this but getting same error

Comment: Ok, give me a sec and I will try it on my machine